# Javascript - Dynamic .filter() - Json File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I need a hint. I'm not a programmer, but I like to take my chances automating processes, excuse me if the question is too basic.

I'm working with the **Google Maps API**, and at some point need to accomplish a filter to target content of my `InfoWindow`.

I have a map with various filters, which apply to markers and should extend to the content of `InfoWindow`.

I have a `JSON` with the contents of my `InfoWindow`, and I am applying the filter it this way: (ards = JSON file)

```
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return n.ERB===marker.getTitle();
});

for (var i=0;i<as.length;i++)
{ .... }
```

Ok, it works, but I need to add more variables to filter.

I own these markers filters.

```
var cluster = $( "#CLUSTER-select" ).val();
var client = $('#cli_re-select').val();
var type_cli = $('#type_cli-select').val();
var type_recla = $('#type_recla-select').val();
```

I put only 4 to exemplify, but has around 10 filters.

The filters are independent, you can select any one at any time.

I made that way:

```
var combine = [];
combine = [];

if(cluster !== '0') {
    combine.push('&& n.DESC_CLUSTER === ' + '"' + cluster + '"');
}
if(cliente_recente !== '0') {
    combine.push('&& n.CLIENT_RE === ' + '"' + client + '"');
}
if(tipo_cli !== '0') {
    combine.push('&& n.TYPE_CLI === ' + '"' + type_cli + '"');
}
if(tipo_reclama !== '0') {
    combine.push('&& n.TYPE_RECLA === ' + '"' + type_recla + '"');
}

var filter_add;
filter_add = "1 = 1";

for(var i=0;i<combine.length;i++){
    filter_add += combine[i];
}
```

The result is: `1 = 1 && n.DESC_CLUSTER === "CTA" && n.TYPE_CLI === "SOHO"`

And I added this variable in my filter:

```
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle() && filter_add;
});
```

But it did not work, he does not apply the values to the result, only the first part.

My question is, how else can accomplish this dynamic filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the each filter is independent, you will need a flag for each filter specifying if that criteria is to be checked or not. If the flag is checked then AND the result of criteria with the filterFlag (this is for filter function). Something like this :

```
var cluster = $( "#CLUSTER-select" ).val();
var client = $('#cli_re-select').val();
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
          var filterFlag=true;
          if(cluster !='0'){
               // Code for cluster
               filterFlag = filterFlag && ____ // add result of above code : TRUE or FALSE
          }
          if(client != '0' ){
                 // code here
                 filterFlag = filterFlag && ____ // add result of above code : TRUE or FALSE
           }
          //......same for others
          //......
         return filterFlag;
    });
```

Let me know if you dont understand this. I will need your code so that I can directly fix it.